# capybara have_field with nil rspec expectation fails on upgrade to 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

After I upgraded Capybara from 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 and Poltergeist from 1.4.1 to 1.5.0, the following rspec expectation started failing in my rails app's tests:

```
it{ expect(page).to have_field("foo_field_id", with: nil) }
```

The rspec error looks like this:

```
 Failure/Error: it{ expect(page).to have_field("foo_field_id", with: nil) }
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find field "foo_field_id" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

If I throw a breakpoint in to inspect, the value is, indeed, nil:

```
»  page.find_field('foo_field_id').value
=> nil
```

If I change "with" to "text", the assertion passes:

```
it{ expect(page).to have_field("foo_field_id", text: nil) }
```

The HTML form field looks like this:

```
<input class="string optional" id="foo_field_id" name="foo[field_id]" type="text">
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

According to https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1169, it's because of a recent change:

> It's not possible to match against nil anymore because to_s gets
>   called on what you pass to with.

The workaround is to do something like this instead:

```
expect(find_field("foo_field_id").text).to be_blank
```